# How to use dynamic variables(tuple) in pandasql query?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pandasql

number_tuple = (1,4,6,3)
sensex_quaterly_df = psql.sqldf("SELECT * FROM sensex_df 
WHERE 'Num' IN ('number_tuple')")

"HERE number_tuple has the values that I want to retrieve from sensex_df database"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `pandasql` allows you to run SQL on data frames, you can build SQL with concatenated values of tuple into comma-separated string using `string.join()`.

```
number_tuple = (1,4,6,3)
in_values = ", ".join(str(i) for i in number_tuple)

sql = f"SELECT * FROM sensex_df WHERE Num IN ({in_values})"

sensex_quaterly_df = psql.sqldf(sql)
```

---

However, concatenated SQL strings is not recommended if you use an actual relational database as backend. If so, use parameterization where you develop a prepared SQL statement with placeholders like `%s` of `?` and in subsequent step binding values. Below demonstrates with pandas `read_sql`:

```
number_tuple = (1,4,6,3)
in_values = ", ".join('?' for i in number_tuple)

sql = f"SELECT * FROM sensex_df WHERE Num IN ({in_values})"

sensex_quaterly_df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params=number_tuple)
```

Comment: The above-mentioned answer is working. Thanks. But, I have a doubt. As we are converting each value in the tuple to a string but actual values to match in the data frame are type int. So, how is this working correctly.

Comment: In order to use `string.join` the numbers have to be converted to string. However, we do not quote the values in SQL so they are treated as numbers.